# Docker best practice on base images and host os

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a questition about the best pratices on using docker in production.

In my company we use SLES12 as host os. Should we use SLES also as base for our docker containers?

In my opinion SLES image is too big to follow the ddocker recommendation for small base images.

My questition is: Has anyone experience in using docker in production with different host and container os? Are there any disadvantages if we use a small debian/ubuntu base image for our containers? (overhead, security, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your assessment that for dockerized applications, smaller base images are preferred. This will save on disk space, reduce network transfer, offer a smaller software surface to worry about security vulnerabilities and general complexity. To my knowledge different host/container distributions is the norm and when they align it's more of a coincidence than an intentional design. Since the way you interact with the host OS and the container are so very different, even if they were identical, you procedures for keeping things patched would be different. That said, depending on your staff skill set, sticking to the same package manager ecosystem (rpm vs deb) may have some benefit in terms of familiarity of tooling, so finding a small base RPM distro might be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In my company the ops stick with SLES. I am a developer and my preferred package manger is apt. There is a movement of concerns taking place at the moment. The ops are responsible for delivering the plattform and monitoring proccess. The devs are responsible for putting the software together with their runtime in bundles. So I think if there is no reasonable recommendation I would stick with debian/ubuntu for my containers.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't run well in containers. Take a look at https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker - it's Ubuntu that has been patched to run inside a container.